# HD parametrer for google oauth using dotnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, .net-core

I'd like to add the [hosting domain parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) to my OAuth workflow to restric the login access to my application, but I haven't found any documentation for dotnet core regarding it.

so far this is what I've done:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(g =>
{
    g.ClientId = Configuration["google-client-id"];
    g.ClientSecret = Configuration["google-client-secret"];
    g.ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey(PlatformKeys.GoogleAuthImageUrl, "image", "url");
});
```

How can I add that parameter to the configuration?
Is that a custom claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom google handler based on the [OAuthHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth.oauthhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

```
public class CustomGoogleHandler : OAuthHandler<CustomGoogleOptions>
    {
        public CustomGoogleHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomGoogleOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(ClaimsIdentity identity, AuthenticationProperties properties, OAuthTokenResponse tokens)
        {
            // code omited for simplicity
        }

        protected override string BuildChallengeUrl(AuthenticationProperties properties, string redirectUri)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            {
                {"response_type", "code"},
                {"client_id", Options.ClientId},
                {"redirect_uri", redirectUri}
            };
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "scope", FormatScope());
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "access_type", Options.AccessType);
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "hd", Options.HostedDomain);
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "approval_prompt");
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "prompt");
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "login_hint");
            AddQueryString(dictionary, properties, "include_granted_scopes");
            string str = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(properties);
            dictionary.Add("state", str);
            return QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(Options.AuthorizationEndpoint, dictionary);
        }

        private static void AddQueryString(IDictionary<string, string> queryStrings, AuthenticationProperties properties, string name, string defaultValue = null)
        {
            // code omited for simplicity
        }
    }
```

I just added the custom domain property to my custom google options like this:

```
public class CustomGoogleOptions : GoogleOptions
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Support for HostedDomain option
        /// https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param
        /// </summary>
        public string HostedDomain { get; set; }        

    }
```

I hope this helps!